# How do I make multiple local notifications on Swift?

Tags: swift

The bottom line is that I made one local notification for a time interval of 10 seconds.
How do I add multiple notifications to this code with different time delays? That is, different notifications with different delays (several hours, days, and so on).
If this is possible, please use the example of my code.
I was told that I need to put a different identifier: "content" and different times. But I don't understand what parts of the code I need to duplicate.

````
import UIkit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        
        content.title = "Hi"
        content.body = "Bear"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.threadIdentifier = "local-notifications"
        
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "content", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        center.add(request) {(error) in 
            if error != nil {
                print (error)
            }
        }
    }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can create method **`scheduleNotification(identifier:content:date:)`** in `UNUserNotificationCenter` `extension` ,

```
extension UNUserNotificationCenter {
    func scheduleNotification(identifier: String, content: UNMutableNotificationContent, date: Date) {
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        self.add(request) {(error) in
            if error != nil {
                print (error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, call this method for multiple notifications with the appropriate parameters that you want to use, i.e.

**Example-1:**

```
let content1 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content1.title = "Hi"
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().scheduleNotification(identifier: "content1", content: content1, date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10))
```

**Example-2:**

```
let content2 = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content2.title = "Hello"
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().scheduleNotification(identifier: "content2", content: content2, date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 20))
```

Comment: So I combine these blocks of code and write them one after the other, right?

Comment: Which blocks are you referring to?

Comment: I mean, do content blocks need to be executed before "request" or after? Everything needs to be done sequentially, as you described?

Comment: There is nothing like any specific order. extension just make that method available whenever you call it.

Comment: Why do I have this error (screenshot attached)
[screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18evOGjgsFiBt6WV3Ucm-d693KfzFI6aW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried searching this error? It is because you're trying to write the code without using any class/struct or any other type. This is not how it works in Swift.